# Empty array does not equal itself in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have come across a situation where  `[] == []` is `false` in Javascript.

Can someone explain why ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't equality check work with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820611/why-doesnt-equality-check-work-with-arrays)

Answer (score 21):

Objects are equal by reference, `[]` is a new object with a new reference, the right hand `[]` is also a brand new object with a new reference, so they are not equal, just like:

```
var user1 = new User();
var user2 = new User();
user1 === user2; // Never true
```

Answer (score 9):

Consider following two scenarios:

```
[] == []; // returns false
["foo"] == ["foo"]; // returns false
```

Here, two different objects are created & those two different instances created on different memory location will never be the same *(object instances comparison compares memory addresses)*. Results `false` in output.

But,

```
["foo"] == "foo"; // returns true
```

Here, `["foo"]` object type is implicitly gets converted into `primitive type`. For now `"foo"` on the right side is `string` so it tries to convert it on `string` (`.toString(), since double equals allows coercion`) and compare `"foo" == "foo"`, which is `true`.

***Conclusion:** we compare object instances via the memory pointer/address or we can say references, and primitive types via the real value comparison.*

Answer (score 5):

Because they are not same object, different object never identical equal, so the result is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

[See Object identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_%28object-oriented_programming%29) because both array create a new instance of array so comparing two different object is not equal. Your code is equivalent to:

```
var arr1 = [],
    arr2 = [];
arr1 == arr2; // false
```

Two literals always evaluate to two different instances, which are not considered equal.

Comment: so how do you compare