# Javascript array equal to zero but not itself

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been playing around with arrays in JavaScript and cannot figure out why this happens:

```js
console.log(0 == 0)
//true

console.log([] == 0)
//true

console.log(0 == [])
//true

console.log([] == [])
//false

console.log([] == ![])
// true
```

The empty array is equal enough to zero both left and right, but why isn't it equal to itself?

I realise that comparing two objects would not result `true`, but why are they coerced to `0` (or falsy, which shouldn't be the case) if you compare them to `0`, while threated as an object if you compare them to the other array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820611/javascript-arrays-cannot-equal-each-other

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are two identical objects not equal to each other?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704971/why-are-two-identical-objects-not-equal-to-each-other)

Comment: @sinisake That would explain why they don't match each other, but the fact they match `0` is confusing me completely

Comment: but `console.log([] === 0)` gives `false`

Comment: @Randy, i didn't dig so deep in javascript under the hood, but i guess type coercion is in question (if that is right term): https://jsfiddle.net/pfy0e9qv/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript

Comment: JS is a very loosely typed language and polymorphism runs through the veins of it. So i would advice you to study [type coercion in JS](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-type-coercion-a-practical-example--cms-21998) topic.

Comment: [] != [], because of them being different objects, other values are same because of == operator doing type conversion before comparison,  You can view useful explanations from these threads,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/empty-arrays-seem-to-equal-true-and-false-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
console.log(0 == [])
//true
```

You are trying to compare object with an integer, so your object is implicitly typecasted to equivalent integer value that is 0

```
console.log([] == [])
//false
```

as two objects are never equal

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log([] == [])
```

That will compare whether array1 and array2 are the same array object in memory, which is not what you want.

In order to do what you want, you'll need to check whether the two arrays have the same length, and that each member in each index is identical.

```
console.log([].length == [].length)
// true
```

Comment: That makes sense, but `[]` definitly isn't the same memory object as `0`.

Comment: @Randy because 
console.log([] == 0) it check if the object is present, and returns true/false. A

Answer (score 1):

Since the complete answer is never given and I actually understand it now, I'll provide the answer myself.

I found this in the Ecma-262 pdf:

It basically reads that `[] == 0` is the same as `Number([]) == 0` which is the same as `0 == 0` which is true. This does not apply to strict `===`.

There is no rule to compare objects other then rule number one, which is `x is the same as y`. This means the same in everything, also memory address. Since they are not sharing the same memory address, rule 10 applies (return false).

> The comparison `x == y`, where `x` and `y` are values, produces true or
>   false. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> 1. If `Type(x)` is the same as `Type(y)`, then
>
>    a. Return the result of performing *Strict Equality Comparison* `x === y`.
> 2. If `x` is `null` and `y` is `undefined`, return true.
> 3. If `x` is u`ndefined` and `y` is `null`, return true.
> 4. If `Type(x)` is `Number` and `Type(y)` is `String`, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.
> 5. If `Type(x)` is `String` and `Type(y)` is `Number`, return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.
> 6. If `Type(x)` is `Boolean`, return the result of the comparison `ToNumber(x) == y`.
> 7. If `Type(y)` is `Boolean`, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.
> 8. If `Type(x)` is either `String`, `Number`, or `Symbol` and `Type(y)` is `Object`, return the result of the comparison `x == ToPrimitive(y)`.
> 9. If `Type(x)` is `Object` and `Type(y)` is either `String`, `Number`, or `Symbol`, return the result of the comparison `ToPrimitive(x) == y`.
> 10. Return false

Answer (score 0):

This question is handled with the knowledge of object reference and type conversion more properly.First,in javascript, object value is stored by reference.So we can tell it is different from [] and [],because the two array correspond with two different addr in memory.Second, '==' is a not rigorous operation for both left and right, [] and 0  are both transformed to `false`.