# Why === and == giving false for following?

Tags: javascript

I know it is very much stupid to ask but can anyone tell me 
Why === and == giving false for following.

```js
x=[[1,2]];
console.log(x[0]===[1,2]);
console.log(x[0]==[1,2]);
```

Here typeof(x[0]) and typeof([1,2]) is also same, then why it is giving false?

Comment: Read up on Sameness Comparisons here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: Duplicate => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820611/why-doesnt-equality-check-work-with-arrays

Answer (score 5):

Because they are different values in memory.

```js
x=[[1,2]];
console.log(x[0]===[1,2]); // Here you're creating a new array in memory
console.log(x[0]==[1,2]); // Here you're creating a new array in memory

var y = x[0]; //Same value in memory

console.log(x[0]===y);
console.log(x[0]==y);
```

[Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)