# Why new Array() is not equal to []?

Tags: javascript

```
new Array // outputs []

[] // outputs []
```

But `new Array === []` is false. Why so?

```js
console.log(new Array === [])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820611/why-doesnt-equality-check-work-with-arrays

Comment: `[] === [] // false` It does not matter how you construct the array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because they are two different references. They can be two arrays with no elements, but they are two completely different objects on the heap.

Comment: Maybe I am understanding it wrong but `typeof new Array === typeof []` is still true!!!

Comment: @Sanjay yes, you are understanding it wrong. Your question's example is comparing two separate objects, but in your comment you're testing the type.

Comment: @Sanjay what does `typeof` ? *The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand*, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof. That being said it is clear why the above expression is true.

Comment: `two completely different objects` This sentence puzzled me haha

Comment: because `typeof` returns a `string`, and they are two objects, so `("object"==="object")` is true

Comment: @Sanjay In the code in your question, `new Array === []`, you're asking 'JavaScript, create a new array for me, is identical to, JavaScript, create *another* new array for me'. Yes, they are both arrays (which is why typeof  returns true) but they're not identical or referring to the same array.

Comment: @Sanjay let that we have `var a = [];` What `a` holds ? `a` holds a reference to an object in heap - a place in memory that have been reserved from your program. Whenever you need to access this object you do so through it's reference e.g. by using `a`. If you want to append an item in this array, `a.push(1)` etc. In the same lines `new Array` creates another array and returns  a reference to that array. So when you call `new Array` and then you use the `[]` you create two objects in the heap.

Comment: @Christos Thanks for your time! Got it!

Comment: @Sanjay you are very welcome. I am glad that I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are constructing two empty Arrays on each side of the comparison. They are not referring to the same array.