# ['0','0','0','1']==['0','0','0','1'] evaluates to false

Tags: javascript, arrays, operators

I have been making a brute-force 4-digit code breaker, but have run into some issues. After some debugging, I found out that `['0','0','0','1']==['0','0','0','1']` evaluates to false for some reason. Why is this and how can I make it true?
[image: ['0','0','0','1']==['0','0','0','1'] evaluates to false]

Edit: I am using repl.it to make this code breaker.

Comment: Because array is an object and here you are comparing the reference rather than the value. JSON.stringify(['0','0','0','1'])==JSON.stringify(['0','0','0','1']) will return true in javaScript.

Comment: Also this SO post: [why-doesnt-equality-check-work-with-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30820611/4003419)