# javascript if function not working properly for index match (apps script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to check whether there are duplicate phone numbers in a column and to then return the first id number associated with the phone match in google apps script.

I created an if statement, according to every reference I've checked I've coded it right. The script runs but nothing populates??

I defined the ranges for the count that has the phone number and id number associated with it. I ensured its in the correct array my using map and used a basic if else statement.

Everything seems to run but the statement doesn't throw out the id numbers. In fact nothing happens.

Please help...

```
function myFunction() {

 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetid'); // sss = source spreadsheet
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('spreadsheetname'); // ss = source sheet

 var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  for (var i=3;i<lr;i++) {

   var phone = ss.getRange(i,4,lr).getValues();  
    var id = ss.getRange(i,1,lr).getValues();

   var phonearray = phone.map(function(r){return r[0]});

    if(phonearray == phone[i]){

    //emailarray.indexOf(email[i]) &&

    ss.getRange(i,30,lr).setValue(id[i]);


    } else

       ss.getRange(i,30,lr).setValue("");

   }
}
```

Comment: `if(phonearray == phone[i]){` what is this supposed to check? `phonearray` is an *array* and thus [it will not be equal to anything but itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820611/why-doesnt-equality-check-work-with-arrays). `phone[i]` is part of the original array that was used to create `phonearray` through `phone.map()`. These two can never be equal but I don't know what should happen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to check the column for any duplicates. was thinking of changing if(phonearray == phone[i]){ to  if(phonearray.indexOf(phone[i])){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There are some things you need to consider

1. A valuerange is a 2-dimensional array, thus to access the value of an individual cell you need to define `phone[i][0]` instead of `phone[i]`
2. The method [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows) requires the syntax `getRange(startRow, startColumn, numRows)` rather than `getRange(startRow, startColumn, lastRow)`. Keep this in mind when you retrieve your range of interest.
3. Searching for duplicates will require in your case two (nested) `for` loops.

Please find below a sample of how you can modify your code to achieve the desired functionality:

```
function myFunction() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetid'); // sss = source spreadsheet
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('spreadsheetname'); // ss = source sheet
 var lr = ss.getLastRow();
 var phones = ss.getRange(3,4,lr-3+1).getValues();  
 var ids = ss.getRange(3,1,lr-3+1).getValues();
 var phonearray = phones.map(function(r){return r[0]});
  for (var i=0;i<=(lr-3);i++) {
        var val = phones[i][0];
        var duplicates = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < phonearray.length; j++){
      if (phonearray[j] == val){
            duplicates.push(j);
      }
    }    
    if(duplicates.length>1){            
       Logger.log("duplicate");
      //emailarray.indexOf(email[i]) &&
      ss.getRange((i+3),30).setValue(ids[i]);
    } else{
       Logger.log("no duplicate");
       ss.getRange((i+3),30).setValue("");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You've definitely helped e get on the right track :)