# Why if ([].length) {console.log('true');} else console.log('false'), gets false?

Tags: javascript

I just saw a js question which is:

What's the result of:

```js
if ([]) {console.log(1);}  
if ([].length) {console.log(2);}  
if ({} === {}) {console.log(3);}  
if ('' == 0) {console.log(4);}
```

I tried with the console and it gave

```
1
4
```

Why `[].length` gives false?  Is the length undefined?

Comment: `0` is falsy. What's the confusion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't equality check work with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820611/why-doesnt-equality-check-work-with-arrays)

Comment: [].length returns 0 is evaluated as false in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of an empty Array is `0`, which is a "falsy" value in JavaScript.

See MDN for further reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy